# What exactly happens in /^.*x/.exec("abcdxsdx")

Tags: javascript, regex

Question was too specific for me to find in the forums.  my console logs "abcxdex", matching the entire string.  I'm confused because to me this means start from the beginning, we will look for .+ or if . isnt there that is ok too.  I am new to this stuff but the 2 ways I am debating how this would be interpreted are clearly all wrong( either look at character 2 for x, , or forget the ^ part and treat expression from character 2 onwards as /x/ since any starting character works.  I thought * means the character it is tied to can happen from 0 to infinite times.  So after . is found to not exist, the next character needs to be x if ^ is mandated.  Please explain in your words what the method of this expression is actually doing.

Comment: Greedy match upto `x`. [ReEx101](https://regex101.com/r/oS0qI5/1)

Comment: the dot is a part of regex syntax. it is not a character here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought * means the character it is tied to can happen from 0 to infinite times. So after . is found to not exist, the next character needs to be x if ^ is mandated

`.` has a special meaning in regular expressions. It matches *any* character (expect line break).

`^` also has a special meaning. It means that the expression has to match at the beginning of the string.

Quantifiers such as `*` are *greedy*. They try to match as *much* as possible, i.e. as many repetitions as possible.

So , `^.*x` means: From the beginning of the string, match as many characters as possible, followed by `x`.

These would roughly be the steps:

1. Match `^`

   ```
   abcxdex
   ^
   ```

   That's straightforward, because every string has a beginning.
2. Match `.*`

   ```
   abcxdex
          ^
   ```

   Also straightforward, because `.*` matches everything.
3. Match `x`

   No match! There are no characters left to match. We need to go back and let the quantifier match less.
4. Match `.*`

   ```
   abcxdex
         ^
   ```

   Match the substring `abcxde`.
5. Match `x`.

   ```
   abcxdex
          ^
   ```

   This time the match is successful.
6. Done. There is nothing left to match in the expression.

---

There are many resources about regular expressions on the Web:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/